# How to split a dataframe column into multiple columns in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, split

I'm reading a csv file with movie data into a dataframe on Python but the main column have multiple columns inside it, like a dictionary. I'm trying to split that column in multiple columns and repeting the same id for the same movies, but can't seem to make it work. Each one of the lines in the csv file looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XMQj.png) and the dataframe I'm trying to split is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/td33W.png). Can somebody help me?

Comment: Have you tried changing the separator in [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)?

Comment: yes, it doesn't work... inside each row of the "cast" column there're multiple 'cast_id', 'character" and the other data, so each row would need to become multiple rows as well